# how make Distinct tuple scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD and I want create a new RDD with unique values, but I have an error.
The code:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("/user/ergorenova/socialmedia/allus/archivosOrigen").map( _.split(",", -1) match {
  case Array(caso, canal, lote, estado, estadoo, estadooo, fechacreacioncaso, fechacierrecaso, username, clientid, nombre, apellido, ani, email) =>(canal, username, ani, email)
}).distinct

val twtface = rdd.map {
  case (  canal, username, ani, email ) =>
    val campoAni = "ANI"
    (campoAni , ani , canal , username)
}.distinct()

twtface.take(3).foreach(println)
```

This is the CSV file

```
caso2,canal2,lote,estado3,estado4,estado5,fechacreacioncaso2,fechacierrecaso2,username,clientid,nombre,apellido,ani,email
2694464,Twitter,Redes Sociales Movistar - Twitter,Cerrado por Abandono – Robot,,,16/04/2015 23:57:51,17/04/2015 6:00:19,kariniseta,158,,,22,mmmm@test.com
2694464,Twitter,Redes Sociales Movistar - Twitter,Cerrado por Abandono – Robot,,,16/04/2015 23:57:51,17/04/2015 6:00:19,kariniseta,158,,,22,mmmm@test.com
2635376,Facebook,Redes Sociales Movistar - Facebook,Cerrado por Abandono – Robot,,,03/04/2015 20:20:18,04/04/2015 2:30:06,martin.saggini,1126,,,,
2635376,Facebook,Redes Sociales Movistar - Facebook,Cerrado por Abandono – Robot,,,03/04/2015 20:20:18,04/04/2015 2:30:06,martin.saggini,1126,,,,
```

Error:

```
scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@dea08cc (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:21)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:21)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What is the error ? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

Comment: Edited. sorry, Im new

Comment: It's ok. Neverthless this seems like a scala version match, did you check if your cluster and your application has the same spark and scala versions ?

Comment: im executing this code in spark-shell, spark version 1.5.2 , scala 2.10.4

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. Meaning, your spark scala version isn't the compatible with your system scala version. Can you check `scala -version` ?

Comment: i may not have installed scala. is necessary?

Comment: I'm not sure anymore. Give it a try !

Comment: This is not due to a Scala version mismatch (see my answer). Also, you don't need Scala on your path, Spark ships with it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the error is due to a missing/additional newline in your csv file.

Your split and match assumes that every line of the csv has exactly 14 fields. Depending on the encoding or text editor you use, you may have additional new lines at the end of the document.

My suggestion would be to validate each line and add a catch-all case that gives you a more detailed error message, that way you will avoid the ambiguous MatchError.